# W: The repository 'http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' is not signed

Tags: update-manager, repository

I'm getting the following error when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: The repository 'http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' is not signed.
```

How can I fix this?

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is as follows:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports main universe multiverse restricted
```

I have changed "Server in South Africa" to "Main Server" in "Software and Updates", but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I visit that repository in a web browser, I get only the same Access Denied message. If the site is still being run as a software source for Ubuntu, then the server appears to be misconfigured.

This repository isn't listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but `apt-get` is using it when you perform the `update` action. This means that it is listed in a file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder instead.

You can find and remove/rename this file in a terminal, if you like, but you don't have to. You said you changed your Ubuntu mirror in Software & Updates from "Server in South Africa" to "Main Server." That's in the Ubuntu Software tab in Software & Updates. Since that didn't affect this particular repository, you can expect that it will be listed in the Other Software tab instead.

[image: Screenshot showing the Other Software tab in the Software & Updates window.]
<sup>My *Other Software* tab in *Software & Updates*. (I'm running Xenial rather than Yakkety.)</sup>

You can then uncheck the entry for `http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu yakkety`, and you should be able to run `sudo apt-get update` without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I installed and ran y-ppa-manager and that did the trick!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```